# how do I write my own production web server?

Tags: select, pthreads, client-server, fork

I am making a unix ssl server/client. So far I have implemented `FD_SET` with select to handle all connections concurrently in one master server process. However due to `__FD_SETSIZE` the number of clients can only be 1024. I need to increase the number of clients and efficiency of the server. Changing the `__FD_SETSIZE` has potential problems (apparently?) so I am stuck.

So far the network includes: errno.h detection, signal detection -> atomic handling, fd_set -> select(), successful stream socket based communication.

I would really appreciate it if someone can tell me what should I do? do I `fork()` after 1024 (which presents its own problems, if its even doable?) do I implement threads to handle each client request, or just client data or both?

What is the best network architecture in your opinion? keep in mind its a socket stream based connection that is meant to handle as much punishment as possible and allowing as many clients to the server as possible.

Comment: Is this homework? You have the two basic mechanisms (processes and threads) in hand already. There is no "best" answer.

Comment: No not homework, I am trying to create a client-server for myself that I can use for my application (anroid/ios) for business. This will allow me to remodel my server easily rather then trying to configure apache. This server should be able to handle as many clients as possible and serve their requests. Currently using fd_set and select I have reached a road block of max 1024 clients. Not sure what to do next?

Comment: What to do next? Don't write your own web server — really — you will get it wrong. If apache is too heavyweight look at something like lighttpd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't write your own production web server.

There are too many [open source servers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_server_software) out there all written by people who know more about high connectivity and SSL than you do. They also have the advantage of being tested to a degree that you'd never be able to accomplish with your homebrew server.

Comment: I am going to use apache for now for my application platform, although I think I will want to make a server of my own for my private communications. I think it may take me a couple of years but eventually having a full understanding of ssl and high level client-server architecture I would like to use it for building my own fully supported client-server applications.

Comment: Thanks, it was an over ambitious project no doubt but I learned a lot about socket programming in C++
Apache works great!